# El modulo Debug Toolbar interfiere con las imagenes

Tags: django

Veran, he instalado un modulo llamado "debug toolbar", el cual sirve para ver datos del rendimiento de DJango. Cuando estoy en el Admin funciona sin problemas, pero si estoy en una vista en la que se muestran imagenes, hace que provoque un error: **'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'**.

Por lo que se, esto se solucionaba poniendo en el settings este codigo:

```
INTERCEPT_REDIRECT=False
```

Pero no ha funcionado.
¿Que deberia hacer?

Más datos:

settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
```

url ubicado en la misma carpeta del settings:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

Por cierto, he comprobado que si quito del codigo INTERNAL_IPS, el modulo no se activa y puedo usar el proyecto de forma normal.

Comment: muestra la configuración que estas usando al instalar debug toolbar

Comment: @GermanAlzate Vale, he añadido algo de información sobre como instale el modulo.